# Sed --- replace a character in a matched line in place?

Tags: sed

In a file containing lines like this one:

```
# lorem ipsum blah variable
```

I would like to remove `#` (comment) character in the same line that contains a specific string, in place. Is `sed` good for this?

I'm struggling to get this conditional working. I have a "clumsy" way of doing this; I can find the matching line number with `awk` or `sed` and then use this number in a separate `sed` command, but I believe that this can be done in a much better way.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Use the string you are looking for as the selector for the lines to be operated upon:

```
sed '/ipsum/s/#//g'
```

`/ipsum/` selects lines containing "ipsum" and only on these lines the command(s) that follow are executed. You can use braces to run more commands

```
/ipsum/{s/#//g;s/@/-at-/g;}
```

Comment: I agree; this is the best answer (although not the only one). Comments: (1) `'s/#//g'` will remove _all_ the `#` characters in the line. If that’s not what you want, remove the `g` (which stands for “global”). (2) To edit a file in place (as asked for in the question), use `sed -i`.

Comment: (3) As a matter of real-world situations, if you want to un-comment a line, you might want to use `sed -i '/ipsum/s/#[[:space:]]*//'`, to get rid of any spaces and tabs immediately following the `#`. (4) You might also want to consider verifying that the `#` is the first non-blank character in the line. The current command would delete the `#` from the line `prompt "Enter # of ipsums:"`.

Comment: @G-Man feel free to update the answer - it's a community one, so it shouldn't require review with your reputation.

Comment: @G-Man - great addition! To your 2nd pt (leading space), what about: `sed -i '/ipsum/s/^#[[:space:]]*//'`?! (`^` signifies start of line, `$` for end of line) - at least in gnu sed...

Comment: @JeremyDavis: Yes, you ***could*** anchor the regex to the beginning of the line with `^`, but that would be wrong. I often comment out indented code by putting the `#` immediately before the code, so the `#` is indented.  I doubt that I’m the only person who does that.

Comment: @G-Man - ah yes, of course! Thanks, I hadn't considered that. So you'd also want to check for whitespace between `^` & `#`, so something more like this: `/ipsum/{/^[[:space:]]*#/s/#[[:space:]]*//}`. Although even then, depending on where the `#` is, it may still cause issues (e.g. in languages that use whitespace indentation/separation).

Answer (score 9):

```
$ cat input.txt
# lorem ipsum blah variable
# lorem ipsum blat variable
# lorem ipsum blow variable
# lorem ipsum blip variable
# lorem ipsum blue variable
```

then:

```
$ sed 's|# \(.*blue.*\)|\1|' input.txt
```

gives:

```
# lorem ipsum blah variable
# lorem ipsum blat variable
# lorem ipsum blow variable
# lorem ipsum blip variable
lorem ipsum blue variable
```

It works as follows:

The `s` tells `sed` that it should substitute what the regular expression finds.

The pattern is `# \(.*blue.*\)` which breaks down to: Find a hash followed by a space. The bracket (`\(`) starts the grouping. `.*blue.*` is the word `blue` with anything before and after. The next bracket (`\)`) closes the grouping.

The replacement is `\1` which is a back-reference to the content of the first grouping bracket.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the POSIX tool `ex`:

```
ex a.txt <<eof
/Sunday/ sub/Sun//
xit
eof
```

https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Comment: That's pretty cool. I didn't know about that! TBH, I'm not sure it's the best answer for this question (IMO the leading sed answer is the one) but it's still very cool! Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this as follows.

```
sed '/ipsum/s/^# //g'
```

This matches all lines containing `ipsum` and removes the comment from the beginning of the line. `^` matches the beginning of the line and `$` matches the end. The rest of the command uses the syntax `sed 's/find/replace/g'` and can be called to edit a file as  `sed -i '/ipsum/s/^# //g' file`.

You can reverse this as follows:

```
sed '/ipsum/s/^/# /g'
```

This will add a comment to the beginning of each line containing `ipsum`.